# How to delete a nested key?

Tags: dataset

This is my data:

```
data = Dataset[<|
   "User" -> <|
     "Edgar" -> <|"id" -> 01, 
       "Parameters" -> <|"Active" -> True, "Region" -> "LA", 
         "Internet Traffic" -> "1 GB"|>|>, <|
      "Anya" -> <|"id" -> 02, 
        "Parameters" -> <|"Active" -> False, "Region" -> "MX", 
          "Internet Traffic" -> "3 GB"|>|>|>|>|>]
```

will get this

[image]

I want to delete some key value, to get this:

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data[["User", All, "Parameters"]]
```

[image]